# CPQ 3rd party portal integration

Tags: website-integration, cpq

### Background

We have to integrate Salesforce CPQ with a 3rd party portal. Looking at the [official doc](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/salesforce-cpq-pricing-editions.pdf) there says that the CPQ+ licence support the kind of integration.

> APIs for 3rd party portals allow you to bring CPQ functionality to an
>   external portal (off Salesforce). This allows users to authenticate
>   access, build quotes with light configuration, as well as request
>   renewals and amendments. Your sales reps can then review the quotes
>   and follow up.

We are not able to find any technical or features documentation.

### Question

**Is out there any other source of information of that capability?**

### Additional Info

We know that is possible to integrate Data (product, rules, pricing, quotes throw the standard API). But we also need to integrate the logic layer of CPQ (rules and pricing application). 
The external website is not (and should not be) Communities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all CPQ API capabilities can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_get_started.htm).